# Retrieve Database record via Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

What I am trying to do is retrieve the record (object) in the database that is the most recent in relation to the record that the user is entering. And get a specific property of that object and use it in a simple subtraction conditional statement.

**JavaScript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#DialogTime').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 600,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Confirm": function () {
                $("#DSCreateForm").submit();
            },
            "Cancel": function () { $(this).dialog("close"); }
        }
    });


    $('.btnSubmitDS').on("click", function (e) {
        // this is where the conditional statement needs to be.
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(function () {
                $('#DialogHighFlightTime').dialog('open')
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Now, the view that has this script on it, is a form... and once the user hits submit, the record they just submitted will become the last row in the table.. so I need to get the property value from the row above the one the user just entered.

I know how to write the conditional statement.. I just need to know how to retrieve the right record.

I might be going about this all wrong, but I don't know how else to retrieve record that is closest to the record that the user just entered.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a insert timestamp associated with the records, you may consider sorting the results in descending order,skip the first one (the one just got inserted) and take the first item.

LINQ might be handy.

Something like

```
var secondLastRecord = db.Issues.OrderByDescending(s=>s.CreatedTime).Skip(1).Take(1);
```

If you want to limit this to a specific user, you might consider adding other condition with a where clause.

```
var userIdToCheck=324;
var secondLastRecord = db.Issues.
                         .Where(c=>c.CreatedById==userIdToCheck)
                         .OrderByDescending(s=>s.CreatedTime).Skip(1).Take(1);
```

Assuming `db` is your DbContext object. If you are using non EF data access layer, you can still use the LINQ `OrderByDescending-Skip-Take` approach. Replace `db.Issue`s with  any `IEnumerable<T>`  which represnts your table data.

Also, to get this in javascript, you need to make an ajax call to server action method where you will execute this code and return it.

Comment: are you doing this in the controller or in the view? Where does `db` come from?